# How to search for a tuple in dict with unknown

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

How would you search for an unknown value in a tuple?

My dictionary is formatted as:

```
d = {
    (0,3): 1234,
    (2,6): 22,
    (1,3): 45,
    (3,4): 55,
    ...

}
```

How would i search to find all of keys that contain the value 2?

Basically, the time expensive solution would be 
`vals = [2 in item for item in d.keys()],`

However, is there any way to use the `O(1)` amortized time complexity of a dict lookup?

Comment: `O(1) amortized time complexity of a dict lookup` yes, by making such a dictionary yourself. In it's current form, you need to search through a tuple for the value. This dictionary is not suited for your use-case.

Comment: Think about what is happening internally when you lookup in a dictionary - it is `O(1)` because you hash the key and then look at the memory location associated with the hash. In this case you don't have the full key so can't generate a hash to associate with a memory location.

Comment: In fact your question is unclear - do you want to find the values associated with the keys which have a 2 in them or do you want to just know which keys have a 2 in them?

Answer (score 0):

No. You use tuples as keys so hashes of tuples are creating. `O(1)` complexity in your dict is allowed only for tuple keys. If you want to find something **in** the tuple, you have to iterate through all keys.

You can create your own dictionary class that stores such info, but I don't think that this way will fit to you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new structure if you need to perform multiple lookups in this manner.

```
d = {
    (0,3): 1234,
    (2,6): 22,
    (1,3): 45,
    (3,4): 55,
}
```

Using a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mapping = defaultdict(list)

for key in d:
    for i in key:
        mapping[i].append(key)

print(mapping)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {0: [(0, 3)],
             3: [(0, 3), (1, 3), (3, 4)],
             2: [(2, 6)],
             6: [(2, 6)],
             1: [(1, 3)],
             4: [(3, 4)]})
```

This one-time O(n) operation makes a mapping, that you can now use for O(1) lookups.

```
print(mapping[2]) 
#Output:
[(2, 6)]
```

And you can use these keys to access all the key-value pairs that match the criteria too:

```
print({k: d[k] for k in mapping[2]})
#Output:
{(2, 6): 22}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no - dicts are no relational databases, and you can only do an exact lookup (like any other hashtable FWIW).

If you have to do this lookup more than once (on a same dict), you could build an intermediate index:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def build_index(d):
    index = defaultdict(list)

    # I assume you're interested in the values, else
    # change the code accordingly
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        for sub in k:
            index[sub].append(v)  
    return dict(index)

index = build_index(d)
matching_values = index.get(2, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a indexing dictionary to associate tuples with their values and use it to get the list of tuples in O(1) time.

```
d = {
    (0,3): 1234,
    (2,6): 22,
    (1,3): 45,
    (3,4): 55,
    (5,2): 97
}

from collections import defaultdict
dIndex = defaultdict(list)
[dIndex[k].append(t) for t in d for k in t]

keysWith2 = dIndex[2] 

print(keysWith2) # [(2, 6), (5, 2)]
```

You would only need to update the dIndex dictionary when keys of `d` change. You can also convert these lists of tuples to list of values (also in O(1) time):

```
valuesOf2 = [d[t] for t in dIndex[2]] # [22, 97]
```